# Get() with status code 200 caught in the exception

Tags: javascript, node.js

A very simple get(), while status code is 200, how come it gets into the catch block ?

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { get, post, patch, del } = require('https');

//const [ getPm, postPm, patchPm, deletePm ] = [get, post, patch, del].map(promisify);
const getPm = promisify(get);

(async () => {
    try {
        const res = await getPm('https://www.yahoo.com');
        console.log('success !');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('failure !');
        console.log(e.statusCode);
    }
})();
```

When i run it, 'failure' is printed out, status is 200, how come ? 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try printing the error. Is `e` just the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case is the use of `util.promisify`. Promisify is for standard "node-style" callbacks, which are functions that are called with two arguments (the first argument is an error, the second argument is the result, if successful).

If you check the docs for [https.get](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback), you see that this is *not* a standard node-style callback, it always just gets passed the result body. This is treated as an error by `util.promisify`, which is why it always rejects.

You would need to write a small `new Promise` wrapper yourself, rather than using the built-in promisify function, for your snippet to work. I recommend you skip the hassle and use the already-available [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module instead.